# Exchange 2010 - No Push notification when when deleting emails from Outlook

Tags: exchange-2010

I'm setting up a Exchange 2010 server for our test environment. I'm running Windows 2008R2 enterprise on this machine. Iv'e also installed all updates available for windows and exchange 2010 including rollup 1 and 2 for exchange that include bugfixes regarding push notifications.

My problem is when deleting mail or marking mail as read don't trigger a push notification. The happens when I use webgui, mobile phone and Outlook 2007.

When deleting a email in Outlook 2007 the changes get sent to the server since the changes are visible in webgui but not on mobile phone. I get push notifications when I get new emails since new emails appear instantly on the mobile phone.

Is this normal behaviour on Exchange 2010? For me it seems a bit funny.

If i force sync on mobile phone the changes appear.

Iv'e tested this on both iphone and HTC HD2(Running Windows Mobile 6.5) with same results.

Comment: Anyone else with the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is not confirmed by Microsoft yet, but after reading hundreds of threads about this issue it seems that this is feature not a bug. It seems that Microsofts Activesync serverside implementation is batching up minor "events" like deleting emails, flagging and marking as read. These events are delayed for (in my case 10 minutes) before they are pushed to the mobile phone. If a new mail arrives the minor "events" will be sent with the "new-mail-notification" that arrives in realtime anyways.

I have tested this issue on both Exchange 2010 and 2007 SP1 and it seems that it can be reproduced in both environments easily.

Please do correct me if you know for a fact that my theory is incorrect. To repeat myself I have not had this confirmed by Microsoft.